# Harvesting plants (specifically Daybloom)

Tags: terraria

I have a garden set up which is about 20-30 tiles across with Daybloom seeds planted in some of the tiles, plus another row 3 tiles above it (forming a tunnel) with Daybloom planted along that too. When I walk along and swing my sword, it harvests all the grown plants.

The only thing is that I haven't been getting much actually growing in it. I've left the Daybloom for about 3 in-game days and not had anything to harvest. What I'm wondering is when I harvest the grown Daybloom plants, because of the large arcing swing of my sword, is it also uprooting all the seeds I've planted or will they continue to grow and just take a long time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments of your question, if the plant is only planted on grass, everything (weeds and plants) hit by the swing of the weapon will be uprooted/destroyed.

So your options are either to use a smaller weapon, wait until all plants have matured, or, the recommended option, use [clay pots](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clay_Pot), which allow for harvesting of single plants.

Comment: One last question - does harvesting from a clay pot destroy it?

Comment: The clay pot is not destroyed on harvesting. You get the plant (and maybe some seeds if the right conditions are met), and the pot stays intact. Just swing at the plant, not at the pot.

Comment: You do, I believe, have to replant the pots after you've harvested from them.

Comment: @SaintWacko Nah.

Comment: Seeds in clay pots are the safest way to "farm" herbs.  It uses a LOT of clay for big volumes of pots (6 clay = 1 pot).  But by the time you are building 500 - 1000 pot greenhouses, you can probably get the clay with a quick scout mission on or just under the surface layer.  Notably, the clay pots can be placed, then a one and a part block layer of lava poured around them, and then they can be planted with fire blossom, that will bloom as soon as they mature. (if you have the level of lava right!)  They don't get destroyed! Great for obsidian potions when you decide to explore hell.